# JS Error when outputting Grid field

Tags: 2.7.0, grid, 2.7.1

I had a Matrix field that I converted to a Grid Field.

The only thing I needed to change was {exp:safecracker} to {exp:channel:form}.

However, after conversion, I noticed that clicking on the "+" button does nothing.

I looked at my console

```
ReferenceError: EE is not defined    
TypeError: a is null
```

[image]

This is the url that is being called

`http://dev-server-2.com/?ACT=7&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,sortable,button,dialog&plugin=markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&file=cp%2Fsort_helper,cp%2Fgrid,underscore&v=1379991682&include_jquery=y`

I am on EE 2.7.1

Any idea what causes these errors? It stops me from actually editing my Grid fields.

**NOTE**

Here is the opening tag in that template

```
{exp:channel:form
    channel="xxxxxxxxx"
    class="form-horizontal"
    datepicker="no"
    dynamic_title="[email]"
    edit_member="yes"
    entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
    error_handling="inline"
    id="xxxxxxxxxx"
    include_assets="yes"
    include_jquery="yes"
    member_id="CURRENT_USER"
    return="/xxxxxx/"
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant template code?

Comment: I think I have seen this error in the past. I can't remember what caused it though. But I know had to fix it by hacking the Safecracker file (this was before Channel Form) and load the EE JS library. These error are so frustrating to deal with because EE doesn't even include the non-minified scripts.

Comment: I also this error before. The url contained some jQUery plugins that serve as clues. Figured out that it was loading some plugins that were removed in the new version of EE. It does not seem to apply in the current case however.